# Piwik (Matomo) creating multiple visits in single session

Tags: matomo

One visit is getting broken down into multiple visits (10+ in some cases).
I’m pretty sure that it’s the same session because all the visit data is identical. Most visits have single action/event.
There can’t be a visit with single Event.
Event is only triggered after the page is loaded. Hence, it would have at least 1 additional page action.
Did anyone face this issue before? Any idea about how to fix this?

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you're using latest Matomo version. if you can reproduce the issue consistently, for example create a small HTML page with the code to reproduce, then create a bug report at: www.github.com/matomo-org/matomo/issues/ and the team will investigate.